# Angularjs ng-model not working input[text])

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a data from the database in a loop and this works great, and the value is in input field, but when i want read this value after click angular return me:

> Object {newName: undefined, newEmail: undefined}

and i don't know why. Please for help.

HTML CODE:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="user.name" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name="user.email" ></td>
    <td><button ng-click="checkData()">Click</button></td>
</tr>
```

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
 $scope.user = {};
 $scope.checkData = function () {
   var data = {
      newName: $scope.user.name,
      newEmail: $scope.user.email
   };
 console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `ng-repeat` code you have displayed each element of `users` & you are showing the one below another inside `tr` of `table`. While you wanted to access the element which you are editing, You need to pass that `user` object to the `checkData` method so that you can have access to that specific specific user.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="user.name" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name="user.email" ></td>
    <td><button ng-click="checkData(user)">Click</button></td>
</tr>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.checkData = function (user) {
   var data = {
      newName: user.name,
      newEmail: user.email
   }
   console.log(data);
};
```

Comment: @Kaker Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: one more question: how to read this data to PHP file, because 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
$userName = $data->newName;
$userEmail = $data->newEmail;
return me 
Internal Server Error(500)
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Kaker frankly speaking I'm from the .Net background..cant say anything on that..for getting attention on your question..you could open new question..and can accept this one :p

Answer (score 1):

In your `ng-click` pass the `user` model such that it becomes `ng-click="checkData(user)"`

Then, rewrite your controller code as:

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.checkData = function (user) {
  console.log(user);
};
```

Comment: @Pankaj was faster :]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the function the data from the DOM you want to evaluate, which is the current user:

You can use

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="check(user)"></button></td>
</tr>



$scope.check = function (thing) {
  var currentUser = {
    name: thing.name,
    email: thing.email
  }
}
```